# glGenBuffers crashes in Release Build

Tags: c++, opengl, qt4

I am facing an odd problem with the OpenGL function glGenBuffers(). 
I'm writing a fairly simple application in which I use a VBO declared in the following way:

```
#include <QGLFunctions>
#include <QGLWidget>

class MyClass : public QGLWidget, protected QGLFunctions {
    GLuint vertexBufferObject;

    // ...
    GLuint makeBufferList(void);
}

GLuint MyClass::makeBufferList(void) {
    vertexBufferObject = 0;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBufferObject);  // <-- Here it crashes

    // ... load data and render

    return vertexBufferList;
}

MyClass::MyClass(QWidget* parent) 
    : QGLWidget(parent),
      vertexBufferObject(0)
{
    QGLContext* context = new QGLContext(this->format());
    initializeGLFunctions(context);
    glInit();
}

MyClass::~MyClass() {
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexBufferObject);
}
```

This all works perfectly fine in the Debug Build. The data is rendered nicely and all and the programme finishes correctly in the end. 
However, in Release Build, the glGenBuffers() crashes the programme. It doesn't just return 0 or do nothing, it crashes right at the function call. But since the problem only occurs in Release mode, I can't use the debugger to find out what's going wrong.

I'm working on a Windows 7 system and developing in Qt 4.8.1. The compiler is the MSVC 2010 (Qt SDK) compiler.

Does anyone have any suggestions that I might try?

// Edit:

Maybe useful to know: I tried to compile exactly the same code on a Mac, using the GCC (Qt SDK) compiler, and both the Debug and Release Build work perfectly fine. But on Windows 7, the problem persists.

Comment: Are you sure it's in glGenBuffers? I'm asking because this sounds like a typical buffer overflow scenario. Breakpoints in release mode are not reliable. Can you place log statements before and after each gl* statements to confirm where it's crashing?

Comment: Have you tried checking the return value of those functions?

Comment: Yes, I did put debug output messages throughout the code, like this:
     `qDebug() << "GL error message:" << glGetError();`

Unfortunately, they return 0 all the way through, until it hits the  glGenBuffers(). Then it crashes, and doesn't even reach the statement right after.

Comment: You don't say how you're getting function pointers.

Comment: Try to change release settings to generate debug files so you can investigate the problem with the debugger

Comment: @NicolBolas: You're right, I should have added that. I edited the code above, and as you can see, I used the QGLFunctions, since I'm working in Qt 4.8.

Comment: @MahmoudFayez: Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't even know you could do that. So I tried that, but it didn't help much. The following happened:
1) The programme reaches the glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBufferList) statement as usual.
2) The glGenBuffers(.) function is located in a binary, so I can only look at it in the Disassembler. It runs through some statements, but crashes at the statement:
   `<+0x000f>         call    eax`
3) An access violation exception is thrown.

Could it be that there's just a bug in the Qt function?

Comment: This is not a QT function it is OpenGl 
did you check this fix?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230976/unhandled-exception-using-glgenbuffer-on-release-mode-only-qt

Comment: Aha, that seems exactly it, thanks! So in short, the problem is related to a flaw in the Qt API, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the the trouble (thanks to @MahmoudFayez): the problem comes from a bug in the Qt API, which makes the glGenBuffers() function (and possibly others as well) crash. The question is directly equivalent to the issue discussed here:

- [Unhandled Exception using glGenBuffer on Release mode only - QT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230976/)
- http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/12794

The solution is relatively simple although not very elegant: use GLEW instead of QGLFunctions.  I fixed my problem in the following way:

```
#include "glew.h"
#include <QGLWidget>

class MyClass : public QGLWidget {
    // ...same as the above
}

MyClass::MyClass(QWidget* parent) 
    : QGLWidget(parent),
      vertexBufferObject(0)
{ 
    makeCurrent();
    glewInit();
}
```

This solved everything. A disadvantage is that this involves using an extra external dependency, whereas using Qt is all about being as compatible as possible, with as few external dependencies as you possibly can. However, it seems that we need to wait until Qt 5.0 is released before this bug may be fixed.

As a final comment: I have not been able to figure out which part in this bug makes only the Release Build that crashes, but not the Debug mode.

Comment: I can believe this is still happening today, 3 years later, in QT 4.8.0. Using glew did the trick but... how come doesn't yet exist any more elegant solution?

Comment: Is it still? Also in Qt 5? You'd think they'd be aware of the issue, as the bug that (alegedly) related to this is https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-5729 and has a Closed status. Perhaps submit another formal bug if indeed it's still there in Qt 5.

Comment: Not too sure if it is still the on Qt5, but definitely on 4.8.0.

Comment: it is still there for `glActiveTexture` and few others and in case of both 4.8.x and multiple 5.x is because initialization is optimized out because done incorrectly (a C-cast from `void*` to function pointer).